# SQL split column value (if column value has more than 5 characters) into multiple rows

Tags: sql, split, rows

I have a table:

```
Name    | Number    
Lisa    | P1234P6953    
Monica  | P0034
Hayley  | P0021P5691
```

I want to achieve the below result. Can someone please help with this? When number column has more than 5 characters, after fifth character it should be splitted into multiple rows.

```
Name    | Number    
Lisa    | P1234 
Lisa    | P6953
Monica  | P0034
Hayley  | P0021
Hayley  | P5691
```

Comment: which rdms are you using?

Comment: What's the maximum number in a single value?

Comment: @shawnt00 maximum 10 characters in one cell (example P1234P6953)

Answer (score 1):

```
-- SQL Server, but fairly adaptable to other platforms
with split as (select 1 as ofs union all select 6)
select Name, substring(Name, ofs, 5)
from T inner join split on ofs < len(Name)
```

Other platforms might have slightly better options. I'm assuming that you have a `substring()` function of some kind and as well as `len()`. For convenience I assumed that you can use a CTE. Generally I would discourage you from saving data in this format as it is not the preferred way to use a SQL database.

Comment: +1 for the answer. It needs some minor edits. In line 2 the first parameter for the substring should be `Number` (though the OP should rename this column to avoid using a SQL keyword). In the join, the parameter for the len function should also be `Number`.

Comment: @Greg You're right. I forgot which column we're operating on.